# AngularJS components in Twig

Tags: angularjs, symfony, loops, variables, twig

I integrated AngularJS in my symfony project which uses twig as templating engine.

But when it comes to using loops, my template crashes:

```
<md-item ng-repeat="{{ '{%item in menu%}' }}">
    <a>
      <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="start center">
        <div class="inset">
            <ng-md-icon icon="{{ '{{item.icon}}' }}"></ng-md-icon>
        </div>
      </md-item-content>
    </a>
</md-item>
```

My console prints:

```
'_item_' in '_item_ in _collection_' should be an identifier or '(_key_, _value_)' expression
```

So is there any nice way to use angularJS loops/variables etc in Twig ?

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe problem in AngularJS syntax, definitely not in Twig. Tested with standard syntax with twig and Angular 1.4.5. This should work:

```
<md-item ng-repeat="item in menu">
    <a>
        <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="start center">
            <div class="inset">
                <ng-md-icon icon="{{ '{{item.icon}}' }}"></ng-md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-item-content>
    </a>
</md-item>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be:

```
<md-item ng-repeat="item in menu">
<a>
  <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="start center">
    <div class="inset">
        <ng-md-icon icon="{{ '{{item.icon}}' }}"></ng-md-icon>
    </div>
  </md-item-content>
</a>
```

In the `ng-repeat` you don't have to use the *braces*.

Answer (score 2):

to avoid twig confusion you should change the angularjs brackets to something else:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{*').endSymbol('*}');
});
```